# Faster method for aggregating this data in R

Tags: r

I have a fairly large dataset (6.5 M rows, 8 cols) that I'm summarizing in a time series of aggregate counts of observations by day.
I'm currently summing across the intersection of two vectors that are the axes in my time series matrix.  The iterations are taking hours to run, and I'm wondering if I'm overlooking something that might give better performance.

My code:

```
m<-length(datespace)
sensorlist<-as.vector(unique(sensordata$SOURCE))
n<-length(sensorlist)

y <- matrix(0, nrow=m, ncol=n)
colnames(y) <- sensorlist
for(sensor in 1:n){
  for(date in 1:m){
     count<-sum(as.vector(sensordata$SOURCE==sensorlist[sensor] & di==datespace[date]))
     y[date,sensor] = count
  }
}
```

I know FOR loops are <strike>less efficient</strike> are an indicator that there's probably a better way in R to get this done.

The crux of this problem seems to be a fast way to create a sparse matrix that fills in the missing summary data with zeros.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data please, e.g. `dput(head(sensordata,100))`?

Comment: Look into `data.table` package.

Comment: For loops are not inefficient. It's the inner functions that are usually the performance sink. That as.vector() call looks entirely unnecessary. Produce an example that includes something that describes the `di`- and `datespace`-object` which are at the moment a mystery.

Comment: I think you're right about the as.vector.   It was in there previously to convert data that R imported as a factor and i needed as a char vector.    See my edit above on or loop inefficiency...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure this is a simple tally:

```
library(dplyr)

sensordata %>%
  group_by(SOURCE) %>%  # or maybe group_by(SOURCE, di)?
  tally()
```

Comment: Almost.  This will certainly do the aggregation for each type and date, but doesn't do the table setup that I need for the input to the graphics library I'm using.   It's very fast though, so there's hope!.  Here's what i used:

Comment: sensordata %>%
      group_by(SOURCE, DATETIME) %>%  
      tally(sort=TRUE)